# Use invokeLater to show dialogs one by one

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, invokelater

In 2 different action listeners, a dialog will be shown when some conditions are met.
If both of the action listeners need to show dialog, 2 dialogs will be shown at the same time. But I want them to be shown one by one.

Simplified code:

```
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getTopLevelAncestor(), "dialog 1");
            }
        });

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getTopLevelAncestor(), "dialog 2");
            }
        });
```

Those 2 "SwingUtilities.invokeLater" invocations are in different classes.

Comment: Why are 2 different ActionListens being invoked at the same time? Sounds like a design problem. You should have a single ActionListener that performs multiple edits (or whatever). Then you can invoke each edit separately and display its display dialog separately.

Answer (score 1):

Make a class that keeps track about that; this class would contain a queue of dialogs to display; whenever a dialog is closed, the first one of the queue is shown and removed from the queue. When another class needs to show a dialog, it's immediately shown if the queue is empty, or inserted into the queue else.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the modality of dialogs. There is quite useful article about this topic http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/modality/. Dialogs have different modality types with different priorities. You can solve your problem by creating the second dialog with lower priority:

```
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane("dialog 2", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog("Message");
dialog.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL);
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: There might be a timing issue involved as well. It works for me when two dialogs are invoked from the event dispatch with short succession. When submitting from different classes things might be different.

Answer (score 0):

You need [`invokeAndWait()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait%28java.lang.Runnable%29), this method waits until the Runnable has been finished.

Or in your situation, when the first dialog has been closed.